# Import data from two sources into one company in quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks

I have two web portals (different domains) but i want to import clients, vendors and invoices from both web portals to my quickbooks using webconnector. What i have tried is creating two qwc files and and configured in the webconnector but whenever i try to import invoice from second company i am getting error of invalid reference.... not found (but the name of client matches exactly like i have on quickbooks with the xml i am creating to run import for invoices ). Below is the error i get when i run import

```
3140: There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Term &quot;Client, Test&quot; in the Invoice.  QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument.  The specified record does not exist in the list.
```

Below is the xml i use to import invoice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
                    <QBXML>
                        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
                            <InvoiceAddRq requestID="39">
                                <InvoiceAdd>
                                    <CustomerRef>
                                        <FullName>Client, Test</FullName>
                                    </CustomerRef>
                                    <TxnDate>0000-00-00</TxnDate>
                                    <RefNumber>Zaztest</RefNumber>
                                    <ShipAddress>
                                        <Addr1>6050 Hellyer Ave #100C</Addr1>
                                        <Addr2></Addr2>
                                        <City>San Jose</City>
                                        <State>California</State>
                                        <PostalCode>95136</PostalCode>
                                        <Country></Country>
                                    </ShipAddress>
                                    <PONumber>Client</PONumber>
                                    <TermsRef>
                                            <FullName>Client, Test</FullName>
                                        </TermsRef>
                                    <DueDate>0000-00-00</DueDate>
                                    <InvoiceLineAdd>
                                        <ItemRef>
                                            <FullName>Bill:ZigSig Fee</FullName>
                                        </ItemRef>
                                        <Rate>141</Rate>
                                    </InvoiceLineAdd>
                                </InvoiceAdd>
                            </InvoiceAddRq>
                        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                    </QBXML>
```

Comment: Post your qbXML request and the qbXML response. Post a screenshot of what you see in QuickBooks.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr.i have added the xml, just to make myself clear more client and vendor import works fine just invoice import is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the *client* (customer) exists...

```
" not found (but the name of client matches exactly like i have on quickbooks with the xml"
```

However, *that's not what the error message is telling you*. The error message *has nothing to do with the customer name*. It's about the *terms name*. The error:

```
 invalid reference to QuickBooks ****Term**** "Client, Test"
```

(Emphasis on `Term` mine). The error message isn't about how the *customer* is named, it's about how the *terms* are named.

Terms are usually something like `Net 30` or `Due on Receipt`. They *should not* be the same as the customer name.

TLDR: Fix your qbXML to send a valid `TermRef/FullName` value:

```
<TermsRef>
   <FullName>Client, Test</FullName>
</TermsRef>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it surely helped as well also i was getting some whitespaces from database when generating xml as well. Now everything works